# Excel 2011 Conditional formatting error

Tags: xml, excel, spreadsheet, xlsx

I made a program that generates xlsx files. I made two files, one [with](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzffQgCAcl7iSmxFcFJNVjA0U1E/view) and one [without](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzffQgCAcl7iZ3VDODZEc3B4ZEU) conditional formatting for this purpose. The file with conditional formatting can not be opened with Excel 2011 (although Libreoffice can open with no errors). The examples are provided in Google drive links above. In the second example i put the `<conditionalFormatting>` element in sheet1.xml and the `<dxfs>` element in styles.xml files. When I open the xlsx file (with cf) using Excel 2011 it reports an error and it tries to repair the file few times and after that the file gets empty (you can try it by yourself).

Does anyone know what I'm missing except these two elements (`<conditionalFormatting>` and `<dxfs>`), maybe I need to add or change something else in order to make it work? When writing the program I was following the same structure as Excel 2011 has when writing with conditional formatting.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Why the downvote? You don't need anything then to unzip and examine the xml files from the xlsx file.

Comment: Here is my fork https://github.com/structer/xlsx . I think the code of my program is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By examining your xlsx files, I see you must move the `<conditionalFormatting>` element just after `</data>` element. I don't have time to write your program to test it, so you need to give it a try.

Comment: I can't believe it, it worked, thank You so much, I thought the order of elements is not that important.